# How to query the count result in this scenario in MYSQL/SQL?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

The table is like this

```
Result
------
type1_choice_1
type1_choice_2
type2_choice_1
type2_choice_2
type3_choice_1
type3_choice_2
```

There is 3 type, for each type, there is 2 choice, for each choice , the **possible data is 1 to 10**. For example, the  type1_choice_1 can be 5, then type1_choice_2 can be 6

I have already insert the data. The problem is I need to query the result. for each column, count the number people choice

That means, e.g. for type1_choice_1, I need to know how many people choose 1, how many choose 2 .... to how many choose 10 . It is the same for other choice

How can I make the query that is most efficient (and readable as well)? Thanks for helping

*note  : Highly appreciate if use the codeigniter syntax, but that does not matter, I can convert the MySQL query to it.

Comment: is 1 to 10 data is in different column or there is just single column and eatch type of data can be duplicate from 1 to 10 times.

Comment: Do you have the table with just the column 'Result' and datatype is TEXT or VARCHAR?

Comment: I would select * and, while iterating over the results, I would accumulate the results in an array (since you posted this as php question I'd think you may use a php solution, even though it seems you are actually looking for a sql answer)

Comment: @Zafar , data can duplicate from 1 to 10 times, so , type1_choice_1 can be 1, 1 , 10 and type1_choice_2 can be 10 2 3

Comment: @user3714582 , that 's all column in the table, I have save that at other column thx

Comment: @giessebi which is better? it terms of simplicity

Comment: That 's ok if sql query is too long / too complex in the end, I will just use PHP  apporach then, does not worth waste time on thinking it

Comment: @user782104 I would definitely go with php

Comment: are you not getting desired results with count with group by your column..

Comment: @giessebi would you mind provide some code example in php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try somthing like this:-

```
SELECT type, choice, COUNT(data)
FROM your_table
GROUP BY choice, type;
```